# Echo/reverb in audio streams using WEBRTC. This happens only on Firefox, chrome works perfectly

Tags: reactjs, firefox, audio, webrtc, mediasoup

I use webrtc to organise online calls and, for some time now, I've noticed that I'm getting echoes on Firefox whereas in the same situation (same output/input) I'm not getting any on Chrome.

I've tried looking at the getUserMedia level by changing the following parameters: **echoCancellation**, **autoGainControl**, **noiseSuppression** but that doesn't change anything.

I have the impression that this is due to the latest browser update.

No problem with Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved in last firefox released.

Comment: I have the same bug, Firefox/120.0 ...